# Personalizar Grid en Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, grid

Quisiera saber como puedo poner un texto en la siguiente grafica, estoy usando Oxyplot, asi como se muestra en la imagen, ademas de poder quitar el recuadro para que solo muestre la grafica.

este es mi codigo

```
 public PageChart()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var model = new PlotModel { Title = "Temperatura Corporal " };


        var rand = new Random();
        double[] cakePopularity = new double[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            cakePopularity[i] = rand.NextDouble();
        }
        var sum = cakePopularity.Sum();

        var barSeries = new ColumnSeries
        {

            ItemsSource = new List<ColumnItem>(new[]
            {

            new ColumnItem{ Value = (cakePopularity[0] / sum * 100) },
            new ColumnItem{ Value = (cakePopularity[1] / sum * 100) },
            new ColumnItem{ Value = (cakePopularity[2] / sum * 100) },
            new ColumnItem{ Value = (cakePopularity[3] / sum * 100) },
            new ColumnItem{ Value = (cakePopularity[4] / sum * 100) }
        }),

        LabelPlacement = LabelPlacement.Inside,
        LabelFormatString = "{0:.00}%"

    };

        model.Series.Add(barSeries);

        model.Axes.Add(new CategoryAxis
        {
            Position = AxisPosition.Bottom,

            //Key = "CakeAxis",
            ItemsSource = new[]
            {
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E"
        }
        });

        var grid = new Grid ();

        grid.Children.Add(new PlotView
        {

        Model = model,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
            HeightRequest = 500,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,

        });           

        Content = grid;
    }
```

quiero que mi resultado quede asi, no me funciona con label ni con text hay alguna forma de hacerlo

[image: error]